# PHP Script Doesn't Run In Chrome Incognito Mode

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, browser, incognito-mode

Having a very bizarre problem. I have a PHP script on a website that runs perfectly fine when I enter the URL into the browser in normal mode. However, when I do the exact same action in incognito mode, it's as if I did nothing. The script won't even `echo` a line at the very top of it to indicate that it ran at all. The same situation happens in Firefox private mode as well.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Let us see the server logs for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between the incognito mode browser and how the server interprets the php code. What the mode could bring to the table is **cache**. There could be a chance you were running a cached version of your website (unlikely).

Make sure you are accessing the correct IP/Domain with the appropriate port.

Edit: Also check if the file you are modifying (it may sounds stupid but it happens frequently) is the same as the one you are accessing.

Comment: You were right. After I flushed the server cache, it worked in incognito.